# Get parameter use FromUri and validate this parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

I get the parameter in my web api action use the `[FromUri]`, for example:

```
public TestController
{
    public ActionResult TestMethod([FromUri] int testParamFromUri)
    {
        //here is my validation
        if(testParamFromUri < 1 || testParamFromUri > 50)
        {
            throw new TestException();
        }

        //other code
    }
}
```

I need to just validate input parameter use attribute and throw new exception if parameter does't valid.
I try to use Range attribute, like this:

```
public ActionResult TestMethod([FromUri] [Range(1,50,"Error message")] int testParamFromUri)
```

but this way doesn't work for me.
Please tell me where I'm wrong or tell me what I should do for validate input parameter.

p.s. I need get input parameter use the `[FromUri]` attribute and validate this parameter use other attribute.

Comment: DataAnnotations.Range is used in class properties, not in method parameters. You can validate using a if statement in TestMethod.

Comment: @RicardoPontual I think I can create the attribute for validate input parameters or this is not possible?

Comment: You can, but it's easier validate in method or simple passa a class as parameter, so you can use DataAnnotations in class. LIke this: public class Param { [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage = "Error Message")]
    public int testParamFromUri { get; set; } }  and public IHttpActionResult TestMethod([FromUri]Param testParamFromUri)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, yes, I know about this way, but I need to use attribute for uri parameter, like int/long/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can creates an `Input` model with a `testParamFromUri` property and validate it using `Range` attribute:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult TestMethod([FromUri]Input input)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        //other code

        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Input
{
    [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage = "Error Message")]
    public int testParamFromUri { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, I know. But I need to use parameters not like a model

Comment: @netwer You can make a request like `http://server/api/Test/54` using this model. Is there any other restrictions that will not allow you to use the model?

Comment: my request is: https://domain/api/data?testparam1=30&testparam2=60 etc.  And I need something like reusable attribute for input parameters, because   create the model for other my api methods I think is not good. P.S. other methods have one or two input parameters